# Output (Display) a random chosen piece of text from a bigger list of text - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, html, text, output

I want to output a couple of lines of text from a bigger list of text saved as a .txt file and and I want it to randomly output itself into a selected div upon refreshing or simply arriving at a webpage. Do any of you "gurus" out there have some idea on how to do something like or similar to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Honestly I have no single idea on how to make this work, I've only written the list and I've prepared the div, but the actual doing it. Unfortunately no I haven't tried anything related to the actual rails application. I don't find the Ruby On Rails API easy to navigate and find what I need, so normally I only seek help through forums and sites likes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_io.html#IO.readlines) method of IO:

```
array_of_each_lines = IO.readlines('filename.txt')
random_line = rand(array_of_each_lines.size)
my_random_line_as_string = array_of_each_lines[random_line]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems by the look of it, to work.
An addition to this comment, I want to ask you where you found this and how you learned it. Through the Rails API maybe? I mean I do not find those docs easy to use :S

Comment: I typed "read txt file rails" in Google, then I found some documentation (the one I linked) and I saw you could create an array from the file. To access to a certain data in an array you can do like: `my_array[3]` for instance. In your case, we needed to replace the 3 with a random index, not bigger than `my_array` size ;)

Comment: oh it was that easy really... well, then I have one last question? Where do you learn most of Rails development from - this is bascially only a question I want to ask an experiences Rails developer, because most I learn is from forums and such?

Comment: I learned most of my Rails basics from the guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org For topics I may not have considered or needed to learn, I learn from things like Railscasts http://railscasts.com Other than that, it's a lot of googling for problems I run into.

Comment: How the heck did RailsCasts and the people on the googling website learn it from, just pondered and made some code from the Rails docs? Seriousely?

Comment: Yes. It sounds crazy but after a while you will prefer Documentation to Tutorials ;)

Comment: Oh well maybe I'll become more experienced some time upcoming. Thanks and a check mark coming along ;)

Comment: After some searching and additional trying I realized that this was Ruby code not Rails code, so I don't think this will work. Or does it?

Comment: Yes it still does. Rails is a Framework, Ruby is the programation language ;)

Comment: In addition, I would strongly recommend http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial for getting a good understanding of the rails ecosystem components.